# Retrieve the APNS's notification when open app

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm not sure if anyone have experienced this case, but it's like this:

I've finished the APNS, the app did receive the notification. It worked fine when I open the app from the notification (which call `appDidReceiveRemoteNotification:`).

Strange thing is, when app is on background, it receive a notification (show up in the notification box). When I open the app by tap on the icon (not the notification), the debugger didn't stop at either `appDidReceiveRemoteNotification:` or `appDidFinishLaunchWithOption:`, so my notification did not saved. When I pull the notification box down again and tap on the notification, the debugger stop at `appDidReceiveRemoteNotification:` as expected. How do I update the notification by open app on the app icon?

** EDIT **

Thanks to abhinav, I realized that I miss-use the method. I should use either

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)iApplication // Or 
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)iApplication.
```

But, my app is design show a server can send message (about update, news...) to the user. The code like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//....
    if (launchOptions) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary) {
            [Message saveMessage:dictionary];

            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
        }
    }
//....
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    // Save message to coredata.
    [Message saveMessage:userInfo];

    // Perform seggue, showing inbox viewcontrollers here.
}
```

But both the method use when open app from background doesn't provide notification dictionary, and my boss required me to update the coredata when open app from background like that, how could I do that? Or should I tell my boss that can't be acquired? We don't want user to miss a notification about updates.

Comment: pls show your block of code

Comment: `appDidReceiveRemoteNotification:` or `appDidFinishLaunchWithOption: ` never get called When your app coming from background. You will be notified by `applicationWillEnterForeground:` or `applicationDidBecomeActive:` delegates when entering fore ground. If you want to update the notification badge then you can do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing nothing different for notification case here. When application is in background and user tap on application icon, irrespective of whether or not a push notification was received, you get call back on below methods.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)iApplication
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)iApplication
```

`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is a method that gets called at application launch time - triggered either first time or a notification. And `appDidReceiveRemoteNotification:` gets called when application is awakened with a notification tap.

**So, to answer your question - you are experiencing natural iOS behaviour!!!**

**EDIT:**

If I were you, I would have gone to my boss and explain the way iOS work. And politely tell him that **its not possible**. When in background, unless user intended to see the delivered notification, iOS does not allow you to get the details.

Comment: But how do I update the notification there, since it has no option like `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`? Also, which one should I use? The `appDidBecomeActive` or `appWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: And more to the question, if I've retrieved the notification by the method you mentioned, how do I remove the notifications in the notification box?

Comment: What do you mean by update notification in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`? I don't think you do that - because user's intention is to launch the app and not to do anything with notification. If user want to see notification, they need to either intercept when it came or, as you mentioned in your question, pull it from notification centre.

Comment: Please see my update @Eddie. Unfortunately what you are looking for isn't possible and rightly so if you think from application' behaviour perspective.

Comment: I'm not satisfy with this answer, but probably it's the only answer. I hope if anyone have a solution for this.

Comment: I wish and pray some solution come around. Although an old thread but take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216016/iphone-how-to-access-the-notification-center-programmatically).

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do exactly? If you want to update your app's badge count then you just need to set application badge count to 0 in applicationDidBecomeActive:

to clear notifications in notification panel use following code :-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```